# Request url on a save way

Tags: php, url, get, request

I would like to read a url. `www.domain.com?cookie=set&redirect=yes`

Now I want to use `$ _SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` but this does not work with `strip_tags` and `htmlspecialchars`.

Also many I read that you should watch for XSS.

Does anyone know how to save a URL can be used by GET?

```
$url = "http://'.$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
$url = strip_tags($url);//doesnt work
$url = htmlspecialchars($url);//doesnt work
```

Thanks!

Edit to (doesnt work):

```
$url = "http://".$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]."".$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
$url = strip_tags($url);
echo $url;
```

for example 
www.domain.com?cookie=set&re**d**irect=yes

output => index.php?cookie=se%3Cscript%3Et&re%3Cb%3Ed%3C/b%3Eirect=yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
$url = "http://'.$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
```

Needs to be either

```
$url = "http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}";
```

or

```
$url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

The way you are currently doing it will not concatenate the data correctly.

Issues with the your line:

1. Your mixing quotes around the protocol `"` to open and `'` to close
2. You are not quoting the `$_SERVER` params e.g `$_SERVER['PARAM']`
3. You are not joining the 2 `$_SERVER` vars with anything so you'll get a syntax error

Comment: Ok i changed that but still strip_tags and htmlspecialchars doesnt work

Comment: Strip tags won't do anything in that context as the $_SERVER values will be URL encoded so `<script>` will be `%3Cscript%3E` which is not a **tag** in the sense that `strip_tags` is looking for.  You would need to `urldecode` the string first

Comment: Doesnt work either... ?r<a href="">edirect=set</a> echo urldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);